# Create Sidebar Nav menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a menu in my Sidebar Nav application.
I try to create but then the result is never what I expected.
Perhaps the problem is in the libraries or lack of some libraries.
That being one of my doubts, I put the libraries that I am using together with the code:

[image]

So I have the following code and libraries:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Expand and Collapse Nav
  $('.toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('#kd-main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
  });
  
  // Nav Items
  $('.item').each(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    me.on('click', function(){
      console.log(me);
      if(me.hasClass('has-menu')) {
        
        // Hide all open nav menus
        $('.item').not(this).each(function(){
          if($(this).hasClass('show-menu')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('show-menu');
          }
        });
        
        // Show/Hide this items menu
        // Focus/UnFocus this item
        me.toggleClass('show-menu');
        me.toggleClass('focused');
        
      } else {
        $('.item').each(function(){
          // Clear all active items
          if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
          }
          // Close all menus
          if($(this).hasClass('show-menu')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('show-menu');
          }
        });
        
        // Make this item active
        me.addClass('active');
      }
      
    });
  });
  
  // Menu items
  $('.menu').find('.subitem').each(function(){
    // Clickable items
    if(!$(this).hasClass('no-cursor')) {
      $(this).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); // prevents parent nav item click event
        $('.item').each(function(){
          // Clear all active menu items
          if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
          }
          
          // Close all open menus after clicking a menu item
          if($(this).hasClass('show-menu')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('show-menu');
          }
        });
        
        // Set this menu item's parent as active item
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
      }); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.kd-p-l-10 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.kd-main-navigation {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(35, 71, 103, 1);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding-left: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: width .2s, box-shadow .2s;
    .inner {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        flex: 1 0 0;
        min-height: 490px;
    }

    .logo,
    .toggle,
    .mainnav .item {
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        min-width: 45px;
        min-height: 45px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .logo {
        transition: width .2s;
        align-self: flex-start;
        background-color: #f00;
    }

    .toggle {
        font-family: 'fontawesome';
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 22px;
        align-self: flex-start;
        transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin-bottom .2s, margin-top .2s;

        @media screen and (max-height:680px) {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            min-width: 30px;
            min-height: 30px;
            margin-left: 7px;
        }

        .bars,
        .close {
            line-height: 45px;
            width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
            min-width: 45px;
            min-height: 45px;
            text-align: center;

            @media screen and (max-height:680px) {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                min-width: 30px;
                min-height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
            }
        }

        .close {
            display: none;
        }
    }

    

    .item {
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
        transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin-bottom .2s, margin-top .2s, background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
        .glyph {
            font-family: 'FontAwesome';
            font-size: 22px;
            width: 45px;
            min-width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
            min-height: 45px;
            line-height: 45px;
            text-align: center;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-smooth: always;
            transition: width .2s, height .2s, line-height .2s, font-size .2s;

            @media screen and (max-height:680px) {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                min-width: 30px;
                min-height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }

        .label {
            font-family: 'OpenSans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            line-height: 45px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity .2s;
            padding-right: 10px;
            @media screen and (max-height:680px) {
                line-height: 30px;
                padding-right: 5px;
            }
        }
        &:hover {
          background-color: rgba(67, 168, 216, 1);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
          z-index: 10;
        }
      
        &:not(.show-menu):hover {
            width: auto;
            min-width: auto;
          .label {
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }

        &.active {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: rgba(54, 111, 160, 1);

            &:hover {
                background-color: #fff;
            }
        }
        &.show-menu {
            background-color: rgba(67, 168, 216, 1);
            box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
            color: #fff;
          &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(67, 168, 216, 1);
          }
        }
      
      .menu {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
        position: absolute;
        left: 60px;
        bottom:0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .2s, left .2s;
        
        .pointer {
          width: 20px;
          height: 20px;
          position: absolute;
          bottom:4px;
          left:-8px;
          background-color: #fff;
          border-radius: 2px;
          transform: rotate(45deg);
          z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .subitem {
          display: flex;
          z-index: 2;
          padding-right: 5px;
          transition: background-color .2s;
          &:not(.no-cursor):hover {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
          }
        }
        .glyph {
          font-family:'FontAwesome';
          font-size: 16px;
          color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
          width: 20px;
          min-width: 20px;
          height: 20px;
          min-height: 20px;
          text-align: center;
        }
        .label {
          color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
          opacity: 1;
          margin-left: 0;
        }
      }
      
      &.show-menu {
       overflow: visible;
        .menu {
          opacity: 1;
          left: 47px;
        }
      }
    }

    .mainnav {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;

        .item {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 10px;

            @media screen and (max-height:680px) {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                min-width: 30px;
                min-height: 30px;
                margin-top: 5px;
                margin-left: 6px;
              &:not(.show-menu):hover {
                width: auto;
                min-width: auto;
              }
            }
        }
    }

    .spacer {
        flex: 1 0 0;
        min-height: 10px;
    }

    .subnav {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        min-height: 110px;
        width: 100%;

        .item {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            min-width: 30px;
            min-height: 30px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-left: 6px;
          
            &:not(.show-menu):hover {
              width: auto;
              min-width: auto;
            }

            .glyph {
                width: 30px;
                min-width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                min-height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            .label {
                font-size: 12px;
                line-height: 30px;
                padding-right: 5px;
            }
        }
    }

    &.open {
        width: 183px;
        box-shadow: 3px 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .37);
        .toggle {
            .close {
                display: block;
            }

            .bars {
                display: none;
            }

        }

        .logo {
            width: 166px;
        }

        .item {
            width: 160px;
            .menu {
              left: 185px;
            }
            &.show-menu {
              .menu {
                left: 170px;
              }
            }
        }

        .mainnav {
            .item {
                width: 166px;

                @media screen and (max-height:680px) {
                    width: 160px;
                }

                .label {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        }

        .subnav {
            .item {
                .label {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.no-cursor {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/fonts/FontAwesome.otf">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div id="kd-main-navigation" class="kd-main-navigation">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="toggle"><div class="bars"></div><div class="close"></div></div>
  <div class="mainnav">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Find Companies</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Find People</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Upload & Enrich</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Prospects</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">To-Do</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Flows</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Notifications</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <div class="item has-menu">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Data Usage</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="subitem no-cursor">
          <div class="label kd-p-l-10">x of y Bundled Remaining</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem no-cursor">
          <div class="label kd-p-l-10">a of b Premium Remaining</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pointer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item has-menu">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Support</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Feedback / Messages</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Help Center</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pointer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item has-menu">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Admin Settings</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Organization</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Licenses</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Users</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Roles</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">KD Licenses</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Reports</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pointer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item has-menu">
      <div class="glyph"></div>
      <div class="label">Settings</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Profile</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Accounts</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Dialer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Call Scripts</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Email</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Invite Others</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitem">
          <div class="glyph"></div>
          <div class="label">Log Out</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pointer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Logo needs to be added once in app using existing logo asset</p>
  <p>All glyphs used here are placeholder and are not to be used as is. Use existing glyphs in the app.</p>
  <p>Tooltips also need to be added to each nav item.</p>
 
</div>
```

But when I check my page it looks like this:

[image]

Can you help to understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's `SCSS`. You need to put compiled `CSS` there. You may also see `SASS` which is like a cousin of the `SCSS` language where instead of `{}` you use the tab indent syntax. Nevertheless your browser cannot understand `SASS/SCSS`.

Secondly, you seem to have not linked your javascript/jquery and css file in the head tag or anywhere.

[Link CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)
[Link Jquery/JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Basic_usage)

[image: View Compiler CSS -Codepen]

Comment: I compiled for css but it didn't work. Can you put the code already compiled and the libraries that are needed to see if it works?

Comment: I leave the [link](https://codepen.io/jamespero/pen/qNqzBO)

Comment: Here in the question I was wrong to copy the code, but in the project I have html, css compiled and jquery, but it doesn't work

Comment: https://ibb.co/kypwGnM. Can you compare if you can find any difference in your code? And yes you will need to put unicode symbols for the icons to appear instead of that strange box

Comment: Please post an image of your project directory like I have done.

Comment: You can put your code in a new codepen so that it is easier to compare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218535/discussion-between-vishesh-mangla-and-bruno).

Comment: @Bruno on codepen you do not need to link your css and js/jquery but on your computer you need to. Also your code is working https://codepen.io/jamespero/pen/qNqzBO

Comment: Root folder image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IahnI.png)

Comment: So just add `<script src="./javaprogram.js"></script>`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">`  in your html file like I did in your <head> tag.